# не работает ocFilter

Tags: php, opencart

Есть 3 страницы с каталогом. На первой странице ocFilter работает, а на остальных ошибка "Запрашиваемая страница не найдена!". Может этот фильтр работает только на одной странице?

Comment: [https://catalog.medion.kz/atmos_product/ЛОР/lor/vstraivaemye-moduli-atmos-] вот так выглядит ссылка фильтра, которая работает. А так [https://catalog.medion.kz/proizvoditel/maico-diagnostics-gmbh?route=product%2Fcategory&path=84] которая не работает. Думаю проблема прячется здесь ?route=product%2Fcategory&path=84

Comment: только не понимаю, откуда фильтр берет название категории в латинице, если я все забивал на кирилице

Comment: исправил пути, нужно было прописать seo url в промежуточные категории. Теперь задается нормальный путь, но все еще не фильтруется, ошибка "Запрашиваемая страница не найдена!"

Answer (score 0):

ocFilter на всех страницах категории... а другие страницы работают, то есть в других категориях есть товары?

может вы не правильно установили

Comment: во всех категориях есть товары. Устанавливал так же как и на первой странице

Comment: ocfilter сразу появится во всех категориях http://joxi.ru/n2YxN79iezZl7m

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6sny14s.png здесь я добавил категории, https://i.imgur.com/OAzO63V.png здесь я добавляю категории в ocFilter, https://i.imgur.com/Ow1KUke.png он не находит эту страницу https://i.imgur.com/4iIDIXU.png. Извините что накидал ссылками)

Comment: даже если нет товаров, не должна же выходить такая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было прописать seo url во всех категориях, и seo url не должен повторяться

Comment: плюс не используйте спец символы, без пробелов